# How to use Bazel for Static Code analysis in Go

Tags: go, bazel

I’ve been experimenting with Bazel and am trying to retrofit my build system to work with it. My project is in Go and I make use of various linting tools and would like to use it with Bazel.

Or is this an antipattern? I’ve used Maven in the past and various code quality tools could be built in.